# Unit Test for div function

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My code:

```
it('div function', function() {

    var bar = function(a,b) {
    if(b==0){
    throw new TypeError("foo bar baz");
    }else return a/b;
    };
    expect(bar(0,0)).toThrowError("foo bar baz");
  });
```

but it fail:

```
TypeError: foo bar baz in file:///D:/Java/AJUnittest/test/test-spec.js
```

Comment: show the error message ?

Comment: I run other code. Please help me